# Is Google's Hangout using encrypted communication?

Tags: encryption

I am trying to use Google's Hangout as alternative to WebEx for sharing screen. But not sure if it is safe.

Comment: Safe how? What are your security goals?

Comment: I wouldn't expect google hangout to be secure beyond what SSL provides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Hangout uses SRTP ([Link](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1279090)):

*"All traffic back to the client from our conference servers will originate from the same port that the client is sending to, and be directed back to the port that the client is sending from.*

*The UDP traffic consists of STUN, RTP, and RTCP packets, with [SRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Real-time_Transport_Protocol) encrypted data payloads."*

And check this for more info: [Link](http://support.google.com/plus/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=1651548&parent=1257349&ctx=topic)